# Spring boot not showing index.html

Tags: java, spring

I have this in `com.tuke.doto.Controllers / RootController.java`:

```
package com.tuke.doto.Controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "frontpage";
    }
}
```

and I have `frontpage.html` in `main/resources/static` (I also tried to move it into `main/resources/templates`

When I do request on `localhost:8080` I see this:

```
HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
```

and in my console on jetbrains intellij I see this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

I've also included `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` into `main/resources/application.properties`

Where is the problem? Isn't that the simplest example so why it doesn't work?

**EDIT** maybe I should install some dependency to make it work...
this is how my build.gradle looks right now:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: suppose you follow this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/) and see what you have missed in your configurations.

Comment: I am using gradle @RajithPemabandu so I can't follow your Maven example

Comment: Hope this would be the helpful [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple)

Comment: I had same problem, and `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` did not work. But what worked was `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})` on the `@SpringBootApplication` class. Maybe this is because I use Spring Boot 2. This solution works when there is another error that is the problem, but since Spring MVC does not have an error page mapped, it fails with the irrelevant error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few assumptions we have to make with this question.  Do you mean **src**/main/templates?  We also have to assume you are using Thymeleaf?  Is that dependency in your gradle path?

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
```

Comment: Yes `src/main/resources/static` or `src/main/resources/templates` - none of these works...
and I've tried to include thymeleaf as gradle dependency but I still get this error:

`Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)`

btw I get it twice

Comment: Are you using Thymeleaf in the way I proposed?  If so, placing the file in src/main/resources/static will never work, because you should only place static content in that directory (JavaScript, Images, etc.).  Thymeleaf will resolve files by name in directory src/main/resources/templates assuming in  you are even using Thymeleaf.

Comment: Yes I am using it exactly as you proposed. Ok I've moved frontpage.html to templates but I still get the same error

Comment: Is there anything in frontpage.html that would cause an error?  Is it static or does it use layouts or tags?

Also what happens if you place error.html into src/main/resources/templates?

Comment: it's static.. for now it just says `This is an index page`... I tried to put error.html in there but still the same error

Comment: It's time to see your configs.  Still not enough information to help quite yet.  Specifically, the files you supplied with **@Configuration**

Comment: You know what? it's my first time after long period with Java, and I actually did change the build.gradle but I didn't run the build... stupid me sorry

Answer (score 4):

IF you are just using static html, you may not need a template library like thyme leaf. Simple return ModelAndViewObject. Place your html in src/main/resources/static

example

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index() {
    return new ModelAndView("frontpage.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adding the following to your configuration class

```
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory(){
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.setContextPath("/myapp");
        return factory;
    }
```

and the following to application.config

```
spring.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.paths=/**
```

put `.html` file inside `src/main/resources/templates`

And then try to access `localhost:8080/myapp/frontpage`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simply run an html file, do ensure that the project structure is the following for a Spring Boot app

[image]

After following this structure, you will be able to access index.html via launching localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

For CRA React, below 2 methods can be used

- Copy contents from CRA `build` folder to either `target/classes/static` or `target/classes/public`

This will automatically map index.html with `MVC`. You can see this during startup of spring-boot application as `Adding welcome page: class path resource [public/index.html]`
Incase this Method fails, alternatively use below

- create a `ModelAndView` object as below

```java
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView frontend(){
  return new ModelAndView("frontend.html")
}
```